# web service having "Method=POST" But there is No Body

Tags: react-native

I have a situation where my web service api is of "Method=POST" type but api does not accept any parameters.

So can any one tell me about->

How to hit the web service  having "Method=POST" But there is No Body.

Comment: Can you share your web service code and your client code?

Comment: fetch("MyURL", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', // <-- Specifying the Content-Type
    }),
    body: '' // <-- Post parameters
  }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log(responseJson);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });

Comment: I am using this Code for fetching the data from service.
Any help would be appreciated...Thanks in advance.